# Ansible set_fact local and use on remote hosts

Tags: ansible, ansible-inventory, ansible-facts

I'm trying to get a version on local and use it as a var in other remote hosts

Using the set_fact module in ansible

On local

```
    - name: Set code version
      shell:  wget -O - -o /dev/null wget -O - -o /dev/null https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/brutusin/wava/maven-metadata.xml | grep -Po '(?<=<version>)([0-9\.]+(-SNAPSHOT)?)' | sort --version-sort -r| head -n 1
      register: shell_output

    - name: set version
      set_fact:
        code_version: "{{ shell_output.stdout }}"
        debug: var=code_version
        run_once: true
```

On Remote

```
    - name: test code version
      debug:
        msg: code version is " {{ code_version }} "
```

Getting the following error: `The task includes an option with an undefined variable. The error was: 'code_version'`

If there any way of achieving this??

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can access variables defined in other hosts with the `hostvars` variable.

For example:

```
- debug:
    msg: "{{ hostvars['localhost']['code_version'] }}"
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the below shared method to **register a variable to persist between plays in Ansible – Different Target Hosts**

**On local**

```
- name: Set code version
  shell:  wget -O - -o /dev/null wget -O - -o /dev/null https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/brutusin/wava/maven-metadata.xml | grep -Po '(?<=<version>)([0-9\.]+(-SNAPSHOT)?)' | sort --version-sort -r| head -n 1
  register: shell_output

- name: Register dummy host with variable
  add_host:
    name: "DUMMY_HOST"
    code_version: "{{ shell_output.stdout }}"
```

**On Remote**

```
- name: test code version
  debug:
    msg: code version is " {{ hostvars['DUMMY_HOST']['code_version'] }} "
```

It works.

Comment: You don't need to define a dummy host. The variable is already available in `hostvars['host_that_created_variable']`.

Comment: Nice workarround that I keep in mind for specific situations. But in the actual OPs case, why not use directly the var registered on localhost ? I also imagine some possible side effects with plays targeting the group 'all'.

Comment: @AlassaneNdiaye, Yes. While writing the tasks I considered local and remote as two different target host groups, and wrote the answer as what I did in past in such a use case.

Answer (score 0):

What about using delegate and running all the tasks on the same playbook? I use that to join kubernetes to a cluster. I delegate a shell command to the master node, then I execute the output of that command on the other hosts of the playbook. I'm pretty sure you can do the same delegating to localhost:

```
hosts: all
tasks:
    - name: Set code version
      shell:  wget -O - -o /dev/null wget -O - -o /dev/null https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/brutusin/wava/maven-metadata.xml | grep -Po '(?<=<version>)([0-9\.]+(-SNAPSHOT)?)' | sort --version-sort -r| head -n 1
      register: shell_output
      delegate_to: localhost

    - name: set version
      set_fact:
        code_version: "{{ shell_output.stdout }}"
        cacheable: yes

    - name: test code version
      debug:
        msg: code version is " {{ code_version }} "
```